# How do I write correct query in nested document?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have two indices: country and person

```
PUT person 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "info": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "int_val": {"type": "integer"},
          "str_val": {"type": "text"},
          "field_id": {"type": "keyword"},
          "country_id": {"type": "keyword"}
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}


PUT country
{
  "mappings": {
    
    "properties": {
      "country_ids": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
  }
}

PUT country/_doc/user1
{
  "country_ids": ["111", "222", "333"]
}

PUT person/_doc/1
{
  "info": [
    {
      "field_id": "1000",
      "str_val": "Jack Kotlin",
      "country_id": "444"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "1000",
      "str_val": "Jack Martin",
      "country_id": "333"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "1001",
      "str_val": "Jack",
      "country_id": "111"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "2000",
      "int_val": 30,
      "country_id": "444"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "2000",
      "int_val": 30,
      "country_id": "333"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "2001",
      "int_val": 30,
      "country_id": "111"
    }
  ]
}
```

If user1 queries '(field_id=1000 with str_val="Jack") & (field_id=2000 with int_val="Jack")' following result must be return:

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "field_id": "1000",
      "str_val": "Jack Martin",
      "country_id": "333"
    },
    {
      "field_id": "2000",
      "int_val": 30,
      "country_id": "333"
    }
  ]
}
```

Help me please!

I wrote a query for **single part**: (field_id=1000 with str_val="Jack")

```
GET person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "info",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "info.country_id": {
                  "index": "country",
                  "id": "user1",
                  "path": "country_ids"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": [
            {"match": {"info.field_id": "1000"}},
            {"match": {"info.str_val": "Jack"}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

and got a correct result:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.1530519,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "person",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.1530519,
        "inner_hits" : {
          "info" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.1530519,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "person",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "info",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.1530519,
                  "_source" : {
                    "field_id" : "1000",
                    "str_val" : "Jack Martin",
                    "country_id" : "333"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**but I don't know how to write a query for multi part!**

Comment: I ran the query you say it works and I see no results. Could you check that is correct?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. One 's' character caused to bug!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will show:

Documents with (id=1000 AND str_field=Jack) AND (id=2000 AND int_field=30)

```
GET person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "info",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "info.country_id": {
                  "index": "country",
                  "id": "user1",
                  "path": "country_ids"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "info.field_id": "2000"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "info.int_val": 30
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "info.field_id": "1000"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "info.str_val": "Jack"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

Comment: But I need AND operation!

Comment: We are almost there , let me re-read and edit

Comment: Done, now its an AND. I put everything in the filter context , that makes the query faster but no scores will be calculated (this will be a yes/no question) if you plan to have better matches than others (e.g: Jack is not a exact value and you expect better matches than others) you can move the second element of the filter close to a must clause.